# Apache : RewriteCond to redirect request coming from unknown IP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Suppose I've website www.abcd.com developed with Linux , Apache, PHP & MySQL stack.

I've webpage www.abcd.com/redirect.php created to redirect all unauthorized users.

If request is made website www.abcd.com or any of it's file in subdirectory [Ex: www.abcd.com/temp/images/aaa.js ] from IP 180.11.34.1 then it should re-direct user to www.abcd.com/redirect.php

Is it possible for to redirect by providing IP range ? Ex: From 180.11.34.1 to 180.11.34.123

Is it possible to redirect all requests coming to my webserver php/cgi/js/css/image files; not coming via my domain, to www.abcd.com/redirect.php ?

Comment: You can do this in with a `RewriteCond` but I would not recommend this as a secure form of authentication.

Comment: Can you please suggest, what will be secure form?

Comment: That really depends on your needs.  Web sites usually use a username and password to authenticate and then sessions to maintain the state.  You could enhance that with an IP check in the application or by white-listing at the firewall level.  Or maybe a solution with a VPN makes more sense - again really depends.

Comment: Is there any good document explaining how IP check can be done along with username & password? Currently I'm authenticating user with user id and password and log entry of IP using $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]. But i found IP address received using $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] is not reliable.... is there any alternate way?

Comment: Not really.  The deficiency is the address can be spoofed by the remote host.  From your end alone it is nice data and a possible extra precaution with authentication, but alone not bulletproof.  More security... use HTTPS, two form factor authentication, or non application layer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for to redirect by providing IP range ? Ex: From 180.11.34.1 to 180.11.34.123

Sort of. You can sort of make a regex for it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^180\.11\.34\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-3])$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php [L,R]
```

> Is it possible to redirect all requests coming to my webserver php/cgi/js/css/image files; not coming via my domain, to www.abcd.com/redirect.php

You can do this by checking the referer, however, the referer can be spoofed so there's no guarantee that you're going to block everything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?abcd.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(php|cgi|js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|ico)$ /redirect.php [L,NC,R]
```